# Div, pinned to bottom that pins to top on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need to implement some intersting behavior for menu on my website.

on a mainpage menu div must be pinned to bottom of the window and when user scrolls down - menu goes up and stays pinned to top of the window.
and when user scrolls back to top - menu goes down and stays pinned bottom.

and unfortunately i don't have any idea how to do so.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Show us your markup. Show us your attempt so far :)

Comment: "i don't have any idea how to do so" @gvee this suggests not much to show

Comment: don't have any markup at now (
but seems like founded decision )
http://jsfiddle.net/virendrachandak/ztrNh/show/

Comment: set the position of the div to `fixed`, add a scroll listener, when scrolling starts and scrollY != 0 change the div from `top:0` to `bottom:0`

Comment: @Alison agreed. But "not much" is better than nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/M3KLB/1/**

### HTML

```
<ul id="menu" class="bottom">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
#menu {
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
}
    #menu.bottom {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #menu.top {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
```

### JQuery

```
var menu = $('#menu');

$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(window).height() - menu.height()) {
        menu.removeClass('bottom').addClass('top');
    }
    else {
        menu.removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
    }
});
```

The idea here is that originally we want to position the menu relatively to the window. Once we would have "scrolled past" it, we should set the position to fixed.

Because we can't *remove* a specific style using JS - e.g. `top` can't be removed - it is best for us to implement this using two different classes. That way the property can be removed and not interfere with our new styling.

The JS calculates the where the top of the menu would have originally sat and compares this with the current scroll position. The reason we don't just calculate the menus position once and store it is because the menu could grow (menu items expanding, perhaps) but more importantly the window size can be changed.

Comment: god I love jquery, screw gsap

Answer (score 2):

Basically, position 'fixed' on the menu - fixed to the bottom.

Then put in a handler that detects when the window is scrolled

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    do stuff . . .
});
```

You can work out the page position

```
if( pagePosVar != 0){
    do animate . . . (menu to top)
}else{
    do animate . . . (menu to bottom)
}
```

i.e. when the page isn't right at the top, move the menu to the top otherwise, move the menu back to the bottom. When the menu is at the top, make sure it's still 'fixed', this time to the top and the rest of the content will scroll behind it.

Comment: Please note that I've slapped the answer in in haste so you'll have to get the correct naming and syntax !